# Most Appreciated

Tags: politeness

I've received a nice comment from a friend, on a work of art that I posted on my Facebook page.
I responded with "Most appreciated, amigo!"

Is this an acceptable 'thank you'? Or should it be 'much appreciated'?

Comment: "Most appreciated!" is an acceptable way of thanking someone, yes. "Much appreciated!" obviously also works, but "Most appreciated!" comes on even stronger.

Answer (score 3):

Both versions are certainly acceptable.

Interestingly enough, a Google search for "Much appreciated" brings up "About 70,100,000 results" and a Google search for "Most appreciated" brings up "About 244,000,000 results" suggesting the latter may in fact be more popular. :)

Comment: Google Search figures are often very deceptive.